# PKCS#11 Test suite

Tags: security, api, cryptography, pkcs#11

Can somebody give me a link to PKCS#11 test suite? This may be a simple utility or part of big project no matter.

I now only this one: [Netscape PKCS #11 Test Suites](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/pki/pkcs11/netscape/)

Answer (score 5):

[OpenSC package](http://www.opensc-project.org) includes pkcs11-tool, a very rudimentary test-suite, `pkcs11-tool --test --slot X --module module`. This is just for reference, I'm sure you can find some quirks in pkcs11-tool test suite if you're using a strange or little bit exotic PKCS#11 module.

Answer (score 0):

http://thewalter.net/git/cgit.cgi/p11-tests

also has a good test cases and it's source codes is available through git system

Comment: this one seems a dead link today